# ORA-01741 for DBMS_REDEFINITION with invisible fields and implicit constraints

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, redefinition, ora-01741

I recently noticed an odd failure pattern recently in one database (12cR1) when using `DBMS_REDEFINITION`.  `CAN_REDEF_TABLE` completes fine, as does `START_REDEF_TABLE`, but `COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS` fails with a bewildering:

> ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier

After some debugging, the exception appears to be related to the `ORIG_TABLE` carrying **both** `INVISIBLE` column(s) **and** implicit system-named constraints.  I'll include an example below to demonstrate the problem, but I hoped to gain some understanding of the behavior, and didn't see anything notable about `INVISIBLE` called out in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm#ARPLS042).

It seems there is some nuance to the creation of system-generated constraints I'd like to understand better.  Apologies for the "why" question, but, Why do implicit system constraints behave any differently than explicitly-defined constraints during redefinition?  I had thought that after being assigned a system-generated name, a constraint was just a constraint.  Are system-generated objects different in other ways from client-named constraints beyond their names?

I also hoped to see if anyone has another workaround to recommend beyond just renaming implicit constraints or un-hiding the columns before the redifinition.

Thanks

Example:
Below are three versions of the same `ORIG_TABLE` for redefinition.  The first two both undergo the far-below redefinition ok with the given `INT_TABLE`, but the third throws the `ORA-01741` during `COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS`.

Version 1: All columns visible, implicit system-generated constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE REDEF_TARGET (
  THE_KEY  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
  THE_DATE DATE    NOT NULL
);
```

Version 2: INVISIBLE column present, explicit constraint (given an absurd name here to poke at if `DBMS_REDEFINITION` is instrumenting existing names)

```
CREATE TABLE REDEF_TARGET (
  THE_KEY  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
  THE_DATE DATE INVISIBLE ,
  CONSTRAINT SYS_C02583271 CHECK (THE_DATE IS NOT NULL)
);
```

Version 3:  `INVISIBLE` column and implicit constraint both present

```
CREATE TABLE REDEF_TARGET (
  THE_KEY  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
  THE_DATE DATE INVISIBLE NOT NULL
);
```

Running either of the first against the below will work, while the third will fail during copy-deps.

```
CREATE TABLE REDEFINER (
  THE_KEY  INTEGER ,
  THE_DATE DATE
);

DECLARE
  V_NUM INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , TNAME => 'REDEF_TARGET');
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER');
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER' , NUM_ERRORS => V_NUM);
  DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you do not need to use `NOT NULL` with `PRIMARY KEY` clause. Get rid of *such* `NOT NULL`s.

Let's run your statement for version 3 on *DB version 12cR1* as in your case :

```
Connected to Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 
Connected as hr

SQL> CREATE TABLE REDEF_TARGET (
  2    THE_KEY  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
  3    THE_DATE DATE INVISIBLE NOT NULL
  4  );

Table created

SQL> CREATE TABLE REDEFINER(
  2    THE_KEY  INTEGER,
  3    THE_DATE DATE
  4  );

Table created

SQL> DECLARE
  2    V_NUM INTEGER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , TNAME => 'REDEF_TARGET');
  5    DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER');
  6    DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER' , NUM_ERRORS => V_NUM);
  7    DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER');
  8  END;
  9  /

ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 1646
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 2502
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 3803
ORA-06512: at line 7

SQL> DROP TABLE REDEF_TARGET;

Table dropped

SQL> DROP TABLE REDEFINER;

DROP TABLE REDEFINER

ORA-12083: must use DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW to drop "HR"."REDEFINER"

SQL> DROP MATERIALIZED VIEW REDEFINER;

Materialized view dropped

SQL> DROP TABLE REDEFINER;

Table dropped

SQL> CREATE TABLE REDEF_TARGET (
  2    THE_KEY  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
  3    THE_DATE DATE INVISIBLE NOT NULL
  4  );

Table created

SQL> CREATE TABLE REDEFINER(
  2    THE_KEY  INTEGER,
  3    THE_DATE DATE INVISIBLE
  4  );

Table created

SQL> DECLARE
  2    V_NUM INTEGER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , TNAME => 'REDEF_TARGET');
  5    DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER');
  6    DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER' , NUM_ERRORS => V_NUM);
  7    DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER');
  8  END;
  9  /

ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 1646
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 2502
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 3803
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

and *DB version 12cR2* :

```
Connected to Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 
Connected as hr

SQL> CREATE TABLE REDEF_TARGET (
  2    THE_KEY  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
  3    THE_DATE DATE INVISIBLE NOT NULL
  4  );

Table created

SQL> CREATE TABLE REDEFINER(
  2    THE_KEY  INTEGER,
  3    THE_DATE DATE
  4  );

Table created

SQL> DECLARE
  2    V_NUM INTEGER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , TNAME => 'REDEF_TARGET');
  5    DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER');
  6    DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER' , NUM_ERRORS => V_NUM);
  7    DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER');
  8  END;
  9  /

ORA-042067: invalid column mapping with invisible columns on original or interim table
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 109
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 3887
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 5208
ORA-06512: at line 5

SQL> DROP TABLE REDEF_TARGET;

Table dropped

SQL> DROP TABLE REDEFINER;

Table dropped

SQL> CREATE TABLE REDEF_TARGET (
  2    THE_KEY  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,
  3    THE_DATE DATE INVISIBLE NOT NULL
  4  );

Table created

SQL> CREATE TABLE REDEFINER(
  2    THE_KEY  INTEGER,
  3    THE_DATE DATE INVISIBLE
  4  );

Table created

SQL> DECLARE
  2    V_NUM INTEGER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    DBMS_REDEFINITION.CAN_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , TNAME => 'REDEF_TARGET');
  5    DBMS_REDEFINITION.START_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER');
  6    DBMS_REDEFINITION.COPY_TABLE_DEPENDENTS(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER' , NUM_ERRORS => V_NUM);
  7    DBMS_REDEFINITION.FINISH_REDEF_TABLE(UNAME => USER , ORIG_TABLE => 'REDEF_TARGET' , INT_TABLE => 'REDEFINER');
  8  END;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

*So, Results follow* :

- Version 12c Release 1 suppresses the main problem of being
  `ORA-042067` instead of `ORA-01741`. So, `INVISIBLE` option needed to be added for `THE_DATE (DATE)` column of `REDEFINER` table for true column mappings between `original` and `interim` tables.
- Even if `INVISIBLE` option added for above mentioned column, you'll
  get still the same error code ( `ORA-01741` ) for version *R1*, while
  you'll be successful for version *R2*. So, upgrade seems to be
  necessary.
- By the way every time we try to drop `REDEFINER` table, materialized
  view needed to be dropped for *R1*, but no for *R2*. Interesting, might be a bug ...

Comment: Thanks Barbaros.  Interesting that `orig` and `int` both need to have the same visibility in 12cR2.  That will be helpful in future redefs after upgrading.

Comment: @alexgibbs Thank you too Alex for such a nice question related to my main subject(Oracle).

Answer (score 1):

it seems due to oracle bug.the bug is fixed on oracle 12.2.
the following is some key information:

Bug 17871192 : ILM POLICY FAILS WITH ORA-01741 ON TABLE WITH INVISIBLE COLUMN

### PROBLEM:

An ADO Policy on a table with added invisible not null default column fails 
with the following message:

ORA-12012: error on auto execute of job "SYS"."ILMJOB2628"
ORA-1741: illegal zero-length identifier
ORA-6512: at "SYS.DBMS_REDEFINITION", line 2525

### DIAGNOSTIC ANALYSIS:

To reproduce, you need a table which had a column with the following command 
added:

alter table "ILMT3" add "C4" varchar2 (10) invisible default ' ' not null;

All three attributes are needed to reproduce.

### WORKAROUND:

Dont use one of the attributes

RELEASE NOTES:

]] INVISIBLE COLUMN metadata is missing.

REDISCOVERY INFORMATION:

In INVISIBLE COLUMN column name is missing then you are hitting this issue.

Comment: This looks like it might have been cut'n'pasted from an Oracle Support document. If so, you need to be careful, as you may be in breach of the MOS T&Cs.

Comment: Thanks yaoweijq.  Good to know this is indeed a bug as opposed to nuance in implicit vs explicit constraints.